# Splitting string into character-limited chunks with pagination/chunk numbers

Tags: javascript, split, iteration

I'm trying to split a string into character-limited chunks by space that includes pagination/chunk parts.

As an example, if the chunk character limit is 30 and the input string is `This is a string which should be split into two.`, the string should be... well, split into two since the character count is 48 (the pagination also takes up character count), e.g. `['This is a string which 1/2', 'should be split into two. 2/2']`.

This is my code so far:

```js
function chunkify(message, characterLimit = 30) {
  if (message.length <= characterLimit) {
    return [message];
  }

  const words = message.split(' ');

  // Error if a word is longer than the character limit.
  if (words.some((word) => word.length > characterLimit)) {
    return 'Word is too long yo.';
  }

  const chunks = [];
  let currentChunk = [];
  
  // Get the chunks first to estimate the number of parts.
  // (Not sure if a separate loop is needed)
  words.forEach((word, i) => {
    if (currentChunk.join(' ').length + word.length > characterLimit) {
      chunks.push(currentChunk);
      currentChunk = [];
    }

    currentChunk.push(word);

    if (i === words.length - 1) {
      chunks.push(currentChunk);
    }
  });

  // Add the part number per chunk.
  for (let i = 0, length = chunks.length; i < length; i += 1) {
    const chunk = chunks[i];

    chunk[chunk.length] = `${i + 1}/${length}`;

    let itemsToMove = [];
    let isOverCharacterLimit = chunk.join(' ').length > characterLimit;

    // Check if words in the chunk need to be moved to the next chunk.
    while (isOverCharacterLimit) {
      itemsToMove = [...chunk.splice(chunk.length - 2, 1), ...itemsToMove];
      isOverCharacterLimit = chunk.join(' ').length > characterLimit;
    }

    if (itemsToMove.length) {
      // Modify the chunks array
      if (!chunks[i + 1]) {
        chunks[i + 1] = [];
        length = chunks.length;
      }

      chunks[i + 1] = [...itemsToMove, ...chunks[i + 1]];
    }
  }

  const output = chunks.map((chunk) => {
    return chunk.join(' ');
  });

  return output;
}

console.log(chunkify('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu vestibulum purus. Praesent viverra, augue eu dapibus pulvinar, purus quam consequat neque, at euismod purus nunc ut diam. Sed in lectus vel lectus sodales ullamcorper. Pellentesque malesuada mi ut neque euismod, ac facilisis ligula malesuada. Nullam finibus suscipit enim nec laoreet. Vestibulum ornare, leo id dapibus semper, quam risus rutrum enim, vel suscipit odio felis consequat felis. Mauris et dolor nisl. Praesent sollicitudin auctor ultrices. Praesent libero sapien, ultrices vel purus et, feugiat bibendum nibh. Sed a luctus mi. Vivamus interdum posuere tellus nec cursus. Integer ut urna rutrum, sodales orci vel, fermentum nulla. Sed massa nibh, efficitur et tortor non, efficitur tristique sem.'));
```

The output is fine until the original length of the array. Is going through the array recursively the only solution for this? Another issue is that if the character count of the updated part number increases, e.g. from `1/9 -> 1/10`, etc.

Comment: If I understand correct, you need chunks of specific size. This chunk cannot have split words, and should also include the pagination in mentioned size. Please rectify if I have misunderstood

Comment: Correct, @Rajesh

Comment: `should also include the pagination in mentioned size`  That makes this into a a bit more complex a problem.. If we don't know in advance what space pagination takes up, then we can't work out how much text we can include in a line.  If pagination could be assumed to be 999/999, things could be made easier, but what about 9/9  or even 9999/9999.  You could maybe say do a first pass to estimate page count, but it would still be an estimate and could still fail.  A much better approach would be a multi-pass, first assume 9/9, if it fails, go back and try  99/99, and then 999/999 etc. etc.

Comment: @dork  I've updated my answer to do the `/9` `/99` `/999` page reflow check, I think this should cope with everything you mention above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```js
function chunkify(message, characterLimit = 30, errorMessage = 'Word is too long yo.') {
  if (message.length <= characterLimit) {
    return [message];
  }

  const words = message.split(' ');
  
  if (words.some((word) => word.length > characterLimit)) {
    throw(errorMessage);
  }

  let chunks = [];
  let currentChunk = [];
  let wordsCopy = [...words];
  let currentPage = 1;
  let pageCount = 1;
  let pageCountLength = 1;
  let didPageCountLengthChange = false;

  const getPaginationTemplate = (currentPage, pageCount) => {
    let currentPagePlaceholder = '';
    let pageCountPlaceholder = '';

    for (let i = 0, length = currentPage.toString().length; i < length; i += 1) {
      currentPagePlaceholder += '-';
    }

    for (let i = 0, length = pageCount.toString().length; i < length; i += 1) {
      pageCountPlaceholder += '-';
    }

    return ` ${currentPagePlaceholder}/${pageCountPlaceholder}`;
  };

  while (wordsCopy.length) {
    // Do it again T_T
    if (didPageCountLengthChange) {
      chunks = [];
      currentChunk = [];
      wordsCopy = [...words];
      currentPage = 1;
      didPageCountLengthChange = false;
    }

    const nextWord = wordsCopy.shift();

    currentChunk.push(nextWord);

    let isOverCharacterLimit = currentChunk.join(' ').length + getPaginationTemplate(currentPage, pageCount).length > characterLimit;

    // Check if a word and the pagination won't fit in a chunk.
    if (currentChunk.length === 1 && isOverCharacterLimit) {
      throw(errorMessage);
    }

    if (isOverCharacterLimit) {
      // Return the word to the words array.
      wordsCopy.unshift(currentChunk.pop());

      // Add the current chunk to the chunks array.
      chunks.push(currentChunk);
      currentChunk = [];

      // Increment page. 
      currentPage += 1;
      pageCount += 1;

      // Check if the pagination character length has changed.
      if (pageCountLength !== pageCount.toString().length) {
        pageCountLength += 1;
        didPageCountLengthChange = true;
      }
    } else if (!wordsCopy.length) { // Add the current chunk if it's the last word.
      chunks.push(currentChunk);
    }
  }

  // Replace the pagination placeholders with actual pagination.
  const output = chunks.map((chunk, i, arr) => {
    chunk.push(`${i + 1}/${arr.length}`);

    return chunk.join(' ');
  });

  return output;
}

console.log(chunkify('Hello, World!'));
console.log(chunkify('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'));
console.log(chunkify('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor sed sem nec dictum. Quisque placerat vitae ligula ac interdum. Mauris massa massa, tincidunt non erat id, faucibus consectetur dolor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse viverra justo ante, sed lacinia velit porttitor in. Etiam tincidunt magna nec odio tempus dictum. Ut a elementum quam. Nunc venenatis lacus et nisi condimentum, non mattis erat dapibus. Nam maximus tempor est, eu lobortis lectus bibendum eget. Duis sollicitudin pharetra massa, et lobortis purus fermentum sed. Praesent a ornare massa. Duis consectetur ipsum eu auctor suscipit. Curabitur sagittis enim quis faucibus finibus. Nam vel nulla in libero accumsan vulputate id et massa. Vestibulum malesuada lacus sem, sit amet gravida mi laoreet vel. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.'));
console.log(chunkify('Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'));
```

I just restarted the loop whenever the pagination character count changes, i.e. `x/9 -> x/10`. I haven't fully tested it yet but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a solution based on following assumptions:

> - We have to split string into chunks with an upper limit.
> - We cannot split a word between 2 chunks
> - The chunk size should also include pagination in count

---

#### Logic:

- A `chunk` can have:

  - Words seperated by space
  - Pagination which is in format `x/n`
- A `chunk` also has a fixed max length.
- So, start by getting a list of words. You can do that by spliting it by space. In below solution, I have used `/\s+/`. This will ignore multiple spaces and count as 1.
- Count a possible length of pages. You can do that by dividing string length by size. This is a rough fighre but will tell you how many digits will it hold.
- Now check for length if it exceeds necessary length.

  - If yes, add page number(*not adding final count though. So it will look like `... 1/`*) to it and reset the computed string to value of word and again start with the process
  - If no, check if it is last iteration. If yes, just append all parts and push it in array.
  - If no, just append the word to the string and go for next iteration.
- Now, once you have all the chunks, loop over them again and add the remaining part of page index to string and return chunks.

---

Following is a sample:

```js
function chunkify(str, size) {
  var words = str.split(/\s+/);
  var chunks = [];
  var possiblePages = Math.ceil(str.length / size).toString();
  words.reduce((chuckStr, word, i, a) => {
    var pageIndex = ' ' + (chunks.length + 1) + '/';
    if ((chuckStr.length + word.length + pageIndex.length + possiblePages.length) + 1 > size) {
      chunks.push(chuckStr + pageIndex);
      chuckStr = word;
    } else if (i === a.length - 1) {
      chunks.push(chuckStr + " " + word + pageIndex);
    }else {
      chuckStr += " " + word;
    }
    return chuckStr
  }, '');
  return chunks.map(chunk => chunk + chunks.length.toString())
}

var sampleStr = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu vestibulum purus. Praesent viverra, augue eu dapibus pulvinar, purus quam consequat neque, at euismod purus nunc ut diam. Sed in lectus vel lectus sodales ullamcorper. Pellentesque malesuada mi ut neque euismod, ac facilisis ligula malesuada. Nullam finibus suscipit enim nec laoreet. Vestibulum ornare, leo id dapibus semper, quam risus rutrum enim, vel suscipit odio felis consequat felis. Mauris et dolor nisl. Praesent sollicitudin auctor ultrices. Praesent libero sapien, ultrices vel purus et, feugiat bibendum nibh. Sed a luctus mi. Vivamus interdum posuere tellus nec cursus. Integer ut urna rutrum, sodales orci vel, fermentum nulla. Sed massa nibh, efficitur et tortor non, efficitur tristique sem.'
console.log(chunkify(sampleStr, 30));

console.log(chunkify(sampleStr, 50));
```

Comment: `"adipiscing elit. Mauris eu 3/34"` length is 31.  But to include pagination in count is a bit of a chicken and egg conundrum.. :)

Comment: @Keith Nice catch. I was missing `" "` in length calculation. Have added `+ 1` to add that. Also regarding the *chicken and egg conundrum*, I did confirm with OP in comments.

Comment: The main problem is the edge cases, this can still fail for example if you cut off your input to `lectus sodales`, so it basically straddling the 9/9 or 99/99 choice (chicken / egg territory), it will generate a line like -> `"adipiscing elit. Mauris eu 3/10"` , 31 chars.    It's an interesting problem this one, like I mentioned in comments to OP,  I think the assume `/9`, loop, assume `/99`, loop, `/999` is really the only 100% way of catching all edge cases.

Comment: @Keith I suspected this issue and I accept this will fail for edge cases, but `var possiblePages = Math.ceil(str.length / size).toString();` will minimize it. But to make it full proof, it will take too much processing and iterations.

Comment: `it will take too much processing and iterations`  Not really, if you think about it 1 million lines is still only 6 iterations, and you could even modify to do your idea of estimating, if the estimate is wrong, adjust up / down, and re-run.  Might mean you only need at most 2 iterations then.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this problem is a little bit more trickier than first read.  This is due to the fact you can get edge cases as your page number could cause a reflow.

So one idea is to try different page size's, starting at of course /9, then trying /99, etc etc.

Below is a rewrite of how I think this can be done.  I've put comments in so hopefully it's easy understand how it's done.

If you run the snippet you will notice how the first example will pass first time, this is because it's first assuming 1/9, find's it works and breaks the loop.

The second example will fail with 1/9, it needs another character for numbering, so it try's 1/99, 2/99 etc.  This works and it will return, so second example takes 2 passes..

```js
const tests = [
  "This is a string which should be split into two.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu vestibulum purus. Praesent viverra, augue eu dapibus pulvinar, purus quam consequat neque, at euismod purus nunc ut diam. Sed in lectus vel lectus sodales"
];



function chunkify(message, characterLimit = 30) {
  //let's assume pages are 1/9 etc.
  let tmpPage = "9";
  while (true) {
    console.log(`Trying ${tmpPage} page size`);
    //lets split our letters into chucks.
    let chunks = message.split(" ");
    //keep check of lineno
    let lineNo = 1;
    //function to get a line up to max line length
    function getLine () {
      let ret = "";
      let anydone = false;
      var pg = `${lineNo}/${tmpPage}`;
      while (chunks.length) {
        let newline = ret + 
          (ret === "" ? chunks[0] : " " + chunks[0]);
        if (newline.length + pg.length +1 > 
          characterLimit) {
          break;
        }
        ret = newline;
        anydone = true;
        chunks.splice(0, 1);
      }
      //for safety lets make sure something was
      //done, or we will have a infinate loop, so
      //lets throw err, this could happen for instance
      //if a word was so long it would be impossible to keep
      //within line length
      if (!anydone) throw new Error("Can't do it");
      lineNo += 1;
      return ret;
    }
    const ret = [];
    //now while any chunks let get a line
    while (chunks.length) ret.push(getLine());
    if (ret.length.toString().length === tmpPage.length) {
      //everything should be ok, lets add back the real
      //page numbers and return
      return ret.map((i,ix) => 
        `${i} ${ix+1}/${ret.length}`);
    }
    //add another diget,..
    tmpPage += "9";
  }
}


for (const t of tests) {
  console.log(chunkify(t, 30));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could defer the length part by using just the line number (or omit is as well)

```
//chunk[chunk.length] = i + 1;
// better
chunk.push(i + 1);
```

and add the length at the mapping parts of the joined arrays.

```
const output = chunks.map((chunk, _, { length }) => {
    return chunk.join(' ') + '/' + length;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. The chunk part numbers also take up character count.